# vertical align two class with youtube

Tags: html, css, youtube, responsive-design

i have a box image with  40% of full screen, below this box I have a youtube video (iframe), but I can not align in responsive (height)

I can not insert the video in the class of images because the class has a separate function ajax

how do I then align to 40% of the width of both classes ??

this is a code i have used  it's good for width but not understand because the height in big and not respect the youtube format:

```
<div class="video44"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mZXkhXcZ3AQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
```

this is a css:

```
.video44 { width: 40%; 
    font-family: 'Raleway_Medium';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.video44  { 
    width: 40%;
    height: auto; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;    
}
.video44  iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

this is a result , why the height its' big ??

http://s22.postimg.org/5ayakawch/tst_Kid.png

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the compiled answer, here it is:

```
.video44 iframe{width: 40vw;height:calc((315/560)*40vw);height:-moz-calc((560/315)*40vw);}
```

**EXPLANATION:**

Your HTML:

```
<div class="video44"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mZXkhXcZ3AQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
```

Says that `width="560" height="315"`. So when you set `width: 40%`, it will take 40% of the screen, correct? But as you can see in the HTML, the youtube format doesn't really exist, all they have is `width="560" height="315"`.

Because here the "%" is being used as a percentage of the width of the document, it might be easier to change to "vw". So now the video will be `40vw`.

Furthermore, If we utilize `calc()` we might be able to find the unspecified ratio of this video.

So we now that the difference and ration of width to height is width/height, therefore we are gonna use `calc(315 / 560)`. Then we multiply that by the size we want, in this case `40vw`. And that's it! How does it look?

```
.video44 iframe {
  width: 40vw;
  height: calc((315 / 560) * 40vw);
  height: -moz-calc((560 / 315) * 40vw);
}
```

You need to also add the `-moz-` because Mozilla doesn't fully support it.

What happened to `.video44`? It adjusts automatically due that it is a `<div>`.

And that should work.

**UPDATE**
*To answer the question "How to make a video inside a `div` being inside a container which is not body 100% of the `div`, and the `div` 40% of the mentioned container", here is the answer:*

HTML:

```
<div id="big_container">
    <div class="video44">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mZXkhXcZ3AQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#big_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: red;
}

.video44 {
  width: 40%;
  height: calc(560px / 315 * 100);
  background-color: blue;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The `#big_container` is suppose to represent your bigger container.
I also added the colors so you could play around with it.

By the way, if you are trying to "alliniate" it, then I recoment you use `<section>`s, and then you make columns with it.

Comment: does not work, this is a result, if you notice not alienate with "box image" I want the video box remain aligned with box image (see) with each resolution

Comment: is `.video44` 40% of the total body? If not, what is `.video44` 40% of? Could you tell me what those values are? Sorry to take so long...

Comment: yes is 40% because with the code have posted the width it's good and responsive, but have the problem of heigth , view the site http://bit.ly/1EfgOsL

Comment: So you want the `.video44` to be full width and the video to be 40% of that? Or you want `.video44` to be 40% of full width and the video t be 100% if that?

Comment: i want the video is a 40 % of full screen , because the box image is 40 % of ful screen , so if i want allineate the two class , it's probable setup allso the videobox to 40%